# Need help understanding network interfaces on my machine

Tags: networking, network-adapter, wireshark, device-manager

I do not understand why wireshark and the device list on my computer do not show the same set of network interfaces. Also, I am not even sure what some of the interfaces are. Here are the reports:

Windows 7 Device list:

[image: device manager network adapters]

Wireshark announced interfaces:

[image: wireshark network interfaces (numbers covered to protect anonymity)]

Some of the items I understand:

- Intel Ethernet Connection I217-LM, in both lists. Ok, this is my plugged in network line, fine got it. Makes sense.
- Microsoft WiFi Miniport Adapter, probably same thing as "Microsoft" in Wireshark panel. Ok understand that, its my wireless card.
- Sonicwall NetExtender, ok, I guess this is a "virtual adapter" for my VPN (which is not turned on right now)

Stuff I don't understand:

(1) Why are both my main adapter and the wireless sending packets? I thought I could only have one active at a given time. For example, when my browser runs it is not going to use two different adapters is it? Why is my wireless even running at all?

(2) I was not even aware I had VMware installed on my machine, but looking in my task manager I see there are a bunch of "VMWare" processes, four of them running, so I guess they are activating these "virtual adapters" somehow. Are these "virtual adapters" just using my main adapter? Why is VMWare even running?

(3) What is the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235? This is not even mentioned in the Wireshark list.

(4) Why does Wireshark not show the VMWare "Virtual Adapters"?

(5) Wireshark shows an "IP" column, but the numbers are 8 bytes wide, which would seem to be a MAC address, not an IP address.

Comment: Centrino is your physical wifi adapter (I have the same on my laptop). The IPs you see look like IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @BigChris What is the difference between the "physical" adapter and the Microsoft "miniport" adapter?

Answer (score 0):

can you post the results of ipconfig?
1. wireshark is not showing your wireless as running - why do you believe it is?
You can have both active, although carefully subnetted. One would likely be limited to a particular usage - your browser wouldn't use both in a normal setup. 
 2. . If you're not using vmware, you should stop it running and remove the setups.
 Virtual adapters do use the real adapter.
 3. Centrino is your wireless physical adapter as mentioned. That it's not in wireshark is why I don't think it is running unless you have other proof. 
4. Wireshark does show the virutal adapters - they're just not sending receiving to any amount..
5. Previous comment is correct that they look like ipv6 addresses except can't tell for sure because of the blockout. ipconfig will help identify that info.